# Java8 stream: ConcurrentModificationException while converting a list to another list

Tags: java, multithreading, list, java-8, java-stream

I have an executer service with a thread pool of 3 and each thread is accessing a synchronizedList and converting it to a list of Map

```
List<String> fruitList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
fruitList.add("banana");
fruitList.add("banana");
fruitList.add("banana");
fruitList.add("banana");
fruitList.add("kiwi");
fruitList.add("mango");
fruitList.add("mango");
fruitList.add("papaya");
```

I want to convert this list to a list of map where fruitName will be key and frequency of item will be the value

```
[{"banana" : 4}, {"mango" : 2}, {"kiwi" : 1}, {"papaya" :1}]
```

I tried something like this

```
Map<String, Long> fruitMap = fruitList.stream().collect(Collectors.
                        groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
```

But, occasionally I am getting the following error. How can I resolve this?

```
[java] Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-3" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
     [java]     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1388)
     [java]     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
     [java]     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
     [java]     at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
     [java]     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
     [java]     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
```

Comment: Could you share the complete code to reproduce this?

Answer (score 1):

If `fruitList` is updated in the middle of `.stream().collect()` process, you shall get that exception. A proper critical section definition and synchronization should be created to avoid that.

Although `Collections.synchronizedList()` does synchronization for most of the methods, it does not synchronize `Collection.stream()` and other methods on the stream. You need to synchronize your stream process manually.

That should work:

```
synchronized(fruitList) {
    Map<String, Long> fruitMap = fruitList.stream()
                       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
}
```